# How to sort data in mongodb data in a custom order

Tags: mongodb

[image]

I need to get the result sorted first by status and then by value.
For status sort by Partial, Draft and Approved and the descending order of value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In you case any basic sort would do as you want to sort by descending order (both for string and for number).

In an aggregation:

```
{
  $sort: {
     status: -1,
     value: -1
  }
}
```

Or for a query:

```
db.collection.find({}).sort({status: -1, value: -1})
```

For an other case a "custom" sort does not exists, you would have to aggregate, add a field using pre-set conditions to sort on.